# Facebook Graph API – access denied for public page event

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-apps

I'd like to receive data on a public page event via the graph api. I have been doing this for quite a while now, but suddenly my code is not working any longer.

Take for example the page ID 128431033877314. A graph api GET call to

`128431033877314/events`

delivers – as expected – the list of events for this page. Amongst them, for example, the event with ID 158032248286483. Trying to receive any data for this event fails, returning my favorite graph api error:

`{
  "error": {
    "message": "Unsupported get request. Object with ID '158032248286483' 
     does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does 
     not support this operation. Please read the Graph API documentation 
     at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api",
    "type": "GraphMethodException",
    "code": 100,
    "error_subcode": 33,
    "fbtrace_id": "GN5BhnWsN5O"
  }
}`

I have tried accessing `/158032248286483` and `158032248286483?fields=id`, I have used the graph API explorer to check different versions (2.6 and 2.12), I have tried with user, page and app access tokens. All in vain. Same goes for any other event returned.

As I said – this has most certainly been working before. I can hardly imagine this being a bug, as it would affect quite an important piece of graph api functionality. So I assume I am missing something here. Could somebody please tell me what it is?

Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: _“as it would affect quite an important piece of graph api functionality”_ -  which is what’s happening all over the place right now, because Facebook is trying to figure out this Cambridge Analytica stuff .. https://developers.facebook.com/status/issues/205942813488872/

Comment: same problem - it is not working due to the accessToken. If you open Graph API Explorer and select in app dropdown menu "Graph API Explorer" you will get access token that works

Comment: @moonvader I have tried using the graph api explorer, same error. Can you read the endpoint /158032248286483 via the explorer?

Comment: it is strange - but I also can't get info about this event even with user's access token.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, @CBroe, is right, in lights of "Cambridge Analytica" issue, Facebook was recently closed/deprecated/changed some endpoints. Reading bug reports many people complaining about lost access to some endpoints related to **Events**, **Groups** and **Pages** APIs. But, there actually two types of changes they did: some endpoints of **Event** and **Groups** APIs are deprecated means nothing you can do right now. (They will change/replace/tune it in future). And second part related to **Pages** API, that actually can be fixed with some coding on your side. For the **Pages** API they just forced May 8 breaking changes to take effect immediately. You need to migrate your requests to use **"page access token"** instead of **"user access token"** when you use those endpoints.

More info you can check there:

**Blog post about actions they have taken:**
https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2018/04/04/facebook-api-platform-product-changes/

**Facebook breaking changes:**
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/version2.11